# How can i add a field to dataset from another dataset in ssrs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I want to add a field to dataset from another dataset in ssrs?can anybody help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SQl Server 2008 R2, you might be able to use the lookup functions to join the data inside of SSRS:

http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/03/19/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-look-up-look-down-look-all-around-part-i/

otherwise you can use a SSIS package as a datasource to do you any type of join and then have your SSRS report use that. This is a little complex to setup, and not recommended for production; but it can work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345250(SQL.100).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159215(SQL.100).aspx

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't merge datasets in SSRS.

You can explicitly ask for a value in a text box (using FIRST for example with the correct scope) from another dataset.